# MERN stack: Download .zip file from server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, zip, mern

In my React app I generate a .zip file in the backend from images stored in the mongo db. The .zip file is called all memes.zip and is placed at the public folder on the server side. I want to include the option to download the related file via a download button on the frontend. When pressing the download button, a download of a file is initiated but says "mistake - no file".

This is my code in the backend for the .zip file generation:

```js
const zipFolder = require('zip-a-folder');


// Generate .zip-file of  filePath which contains all saved memes
class ZipAFolder {
 
  static main() {
      zipFolder.zipFolder('./public/share', './public/allmemes.zip', function(err) {
          if(err) {
              console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
          } 
      });
  }
}

ZipAFolder.main();
```

These are my code snippets in the frontend:

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';


// Save .zip-File of all saved Memes
  const saveFile = () => {
    fileSaver.saveAs(
      process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/public/allmemes.zip",
      "allmemes.zip"
    );
    }


        <Button className={classes.button} onClick=               {saveFile}>
         Download .zip-File
        </Button>
```

the import of file-saver is somehow not recognized.

Can someone help with this problem? Would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

remove fileSaver. and it'll work

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';


// Save .zip-File of all saved Memes
  const saveFile = () => {
    saveAs(
      process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/public/allmemes.zip",
      "allmemes.zip"
    );
    }


        <Button className={classes.button} onClick=               {saveFile}>
         Download .zip-File
        </Button>
```